# How to try to convert object to double, and if it fails take it as string ?

Tags: c#, string

I would like to convert object (which holds a string) to double and if it fails (it contains a string which cannot be converted to double) to convert it to string, so that I would have a `List<object>` with doubles and strings.

I have something like this : 
(thisNavigator is XPathNavigator)

```
object paramValue;
paramValue = Convert.ToDouble(thisNavigator.ValueAsDouble);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
static void Add(List<object> list, XPathNavigator thisNavigator)
{
    string s = thisNavigator.ValueAsString;
    double d;
    if(double.TryParse(s, out d))
    {
        list.Add(d);
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend explicitly specifying a culture when using `double.TryParse`, even if it's the current culture.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `double.TryParse()`:

```
object paramValue = ...;
double doubleValue;
if(!double.TryParse(thisNavigator.Value, out doubleValue))
{
    paramValue = thisNavigator.Value;
}
```

But better yet you could use `thisNavigator.TypedValue` which should return the value typed as the appropriate type (but boxed as object) - then you can insert it directly into your list. I have to question the design though - why would you keep a `List<object>` around? There's got to be a better way.

Comment: it's a parameter's value list, they might be numbers (doubles) or strings(like paths etc). One more question: why can't I do this: if (!double.TryParse( thisNavigator.Value, out (double)paramValue))
                                    {//....